# Prove $\bar{uv}=\bar{u}\cdot \bar{v}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> > Prove $\overline{uv}=\overline{u}\cdot \overline{v}$

I can't seem to find a nice algebraic proof for it , I have tried this

let $u=a+bi$ and $v=c+di$

$uv=(a+bi)(c+di)=ac+adi+bci-bd=ac-bd+i(ad+bc)$

$\therefore \overline{uv} = (ac-bd)-i(ad+bc)$

Now $\bar{u} \cdot \bar{v}=(a-bi)(c-di)=ac-adi-bci-bd=ac-bd-i(ad+bc)$

So we are done since LHS=RHS

however this proof seems too long and tedious , any easier way?

Comment: Exponential form for u and v?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\overline{uv}=\frac{|uv|^2}{uv} =\frac{|u|^2}u\frac{|v|^2}v=\bar u \bar v
$$

for nonzero $u,v$ is an alternative proof.

Comment: That's better again.

Comment: `\overline` is better than `\bar` if you want a line over more than one symbol.

Comment: This relies on the fact that $|zw|=|z|\,|w|$, which algebraically is at least as complicated to show as  $\overline{zw}=\bar z\,\bar w$ directly.

Comment: @mrf you are kind of right, but maybe it helps the OP, who probably knows better on what the proof can be based on.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment, let $u=r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $v=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$. Then, $$uv=r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}\implies \overline{uv}=r_1r_2e^{i(-(\theta_1+\theta_2))}=r_1r_2e^{i[(-\theta_1)+(-\theta_2)]}=\bar{u}\bar{v}$$

Comment: This relies on the fact that the complex exponential function behaves as you would expect, which is at least as complicated to show as the computation given by the OP.